# Is it possible to add a elb (cloud provider) to an existing kubernetes cluster running on RHEL8 EC2?

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, amazon-ec2, nginx-ingress, amazon-elb

i have a cluster running on aws ec2 and not a managed EKS, i'm trying to add a loadbalancer to the cluster without restarting it or initializing a new node, is that possible ? i've already set the permission and tags related to this post https://blog.heptio.com/setting-up-the-kubernetes-aws-cloud-provider-6f0349b512bd
But the thing is that we must add the flag --cloud-provider=aws  to the Kubelet before adding the node to the cluster.
Is there any other options or other way to do it ?
[kubectl get nodes][1]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try using AWS load balancer controller, it works with both managed and self-managed K8s clusters https://kubernetes-sigs.github.io/aws-load-balancer-controller/v2.3/

Zee

Comment: Thank you so much